# Aggregating Values for a specific ID in a Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

If I have a dataframe such as

```
id     quantity     date
 1     2.0          6-12-18
 1     3.0          6-20-18
 1     3.0          6-22-18
 1     1.0          5-12-18
 2     5.0          6-10-18
 2     1.0          6-15-18
 2     1.0          6-11-18
 3     4.0          7-10-18
 3     4.0          7-15-18
 3     4.0          7-16-18
```

I want to find the deviation for the 'quantity' column's values associated with a specific id.

I was thinking that I could aggregate the quantity values associated with a specific ID and order the quantity values by date, and eliminate duplicates from the list of integers created for each ID. My idea was to use **df.groupby** and maybe *pd.series.unique*

The goal is that it looks like this:

```
id     quantity                 date
 1     1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0       5-12-18, 6-12-18, 6-20-18, 6-22-18 
 2     5.0, 1.0, 1.0            6-10-18, 6-11-18, 6-15-18
 3     4.0, 4.0, 4.0            7-10-18, 7-15-18, 7-16-18
```

and then I wanted to create a new column within the dataframe where it would state whether the value in quantity increased, decreased, or stayed the same so it would look like this:

```
id     quantity                 trend
 1     1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0       inc, same, dec 
 2     5.0, 1.0, 1.0            dec, same
 3     4.0, 4.0, 4.0            same
```

thanks :)

Comment: I can not match the out put with your input df , would you like check it ?,for example first row

Comment: the dates are out of order, so one of the things I was hoping to achieve was to order the quantity values by date (that's why the output starts with 1.0 since there was a quantity of 1.0 for id #1 on 5-12-2018 [it's on row 4 of the input df]) - thank you though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input (`df`)

```
   id  quality       date
0   1      2.0 2018-06-12
1   1      3.0 2018-06-20
2   1      3.0 2018-06-22
3   1      1.0 2018-05-12
4   2      5.0 2018-06-10
5   2      1.0 2018-06-15
6   2      1.0 2018-06-11
7   3      4.0 2018-07-10
8   3      4.0 2018-07-15
9   3      4.0 2018-07-16
```

Code

```
# date column (lists)
df0 = df.groupby('id')['date'].apply(list).reset_index(drop=False)

# quality column (lists)
df1 = df.groupby('id')['quality'].apply(list).reset_index(drop=False)

# trend column (lists)
df['delta'] = df.quality.diff(1)
df.loc[df.delta > 0, 'trend'] = 'inc'
df.loc[df.delta == 0, 'trend'] = 'same'
df.loc[df.delta < 0, 'trend'] = 'dec'
df2 = df.groupby('id')['trend'].apply(list).apply(lambda x: x[1:]).reset_index(drop=False)

# merge all
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df0, on='id', how='left')
df3 = pd.merge(df3, df2, on='id', how='left')

# remove brackets
df3['quality'] = df3.quality.apply(lambda x: ", ".join(repr(e) for e in x))
df3['date'] = df3.date.apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x))
df3['trend'] = df3.trend.apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x))
```

Output (`df3`)

```
    id  quality             date                    trend
0   1   2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0  6-12-18, 6-20-18, ...   inc, same, dec
1   2   5.0, 1.0, 1.0       6-10-18, 6-15-18, ...   dec, same
2   3   4.0, 4.0, 4.0       7-10-18, 7-15-18, ...   same, same
```

Comment: nice use of .apply(list). I'll take mine down